# Ember Data - Serialization Options

Tags: json, ember.js, ember-data, json-api

I have a model with a hasMany realtionship.

I currently use the EmbeddedRecordsMixin to include the JSONAPI in my payload that is then sent to the server.

My problem is that I wish to send only the JSON representation of this object. i.e without type and attributes hash. Instead I wish to the send the payload as simply JSON  { id: 1, Name: 'Darren', Surname: 'Blh' ... }

How is it possible to convert the JSONAPI to JSON?

Thanks

Darren

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by overriding the serialize() method on the serializer.

```
serialize(snapshot, options) {
   var json = this._super(...arguments);

   for (let i = 0; i < json.passengers.length; i++ ) {
     console.log('Converting Person JSON:API to JSON');
     json.passengers[i].id           = json.passengers[i].data.id;
     json.passengers[i].firstName    = json.passengers[i].data.attributes.firstName;
     json.passengers[i].lastName     = json.passengers[i].data.attributes.lastName;

     delete json.passengers[i].data;
   }
   return json;
}
```